# how to handle Dropdownlist SelectedIndexchanged event in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

```
!{Html.TextBox("registerDetails.OtherCompanyActivity", registerModel.EditForm.OtherCompanyActivity, new { @class = "further_info", @tabindex = "15" })}
```

this is my dropdownlist. And when i have selected a value in the dropdownlist , the textbox should be made readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript

add/bind OnChange event to the dropdown list

```
OtherCompanyActivity", registerModel.EditForm.OtherCompanyActivity, new { @class = "further_info", @tabindex = "15", onchange="dpwnChnaged()" })}
```

Check the value change from default value and make the text box ReadOnly by adding ReadOnly attribute to text box

I would prefer JQuery